# Get url without blocking the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to get a resource from a url inside a route on a web server without blocking it since getting it sometimes takes 11 seconds+.
I switched from flask to aiohttp for this.

```
async def process(request):
    data = await request.json()
    req = urllib.request.Request(
            request["resource_url"], 
            data=None, 
            headers=hdrs
        )
    # Do processing on the resource
```

But I'm not sure how to make the call and would it allow other calls to be made to this route while the resource is getting fetched?

Comment: You should use aiohttp to make the request. Although if you want to respond to the client before the request completes, you may want to use a background worker (e.g., celery, rq).

Comment: as @dirn suggested you should use aiohttp please refer this link to make use of aiohttp client https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request